# Keep group of rows together ordered by min(time) without using group by

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I have a table of events generated by users doing stuff.  It looks roughly like this:

```
session           |   time                  |  event       |  etc.
06efaa1805ef670c  |   2022-01-07 08:41:03   |  lockFound   |  etc.
06efaa1805ef670c  |   2022-01-07 08:41:43   |  lockLost    |  etc.
154032b09bec72f8  |   2022-01-07 10:41:03   |  lockFound   |  etc.
154032b09bec72f8  |   2022-01-07 10:41:43   |  lockLost    |  etc.
```

I need to get all of these events in a certain order:

1. They have to be grouped by the session ID so all events from one session appear together
2. The sessions have to be in order of time (preferably the time of the first event in the session)
3. The order of the events in the session doesn't actually matter
4. I don't want to use GROUP BY because I need every event in the table

How would I set about this?

The actual data is [here](https://dlrcoco.windowsonthepast.com/events_log.php)

Retrieved by:

```
SELECT * FROM dlrcoco_events ORDER BY time DESC`
```

Comment: I think yo are asking for `ORDER BY session ASC, time ASC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using MySQL 8 or later then you can use window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM dlrcoco_events
ORDER BY MIN(time) OVER (PARTITION BY session), session, time
```

Explanation of order by:

- First column will contain the time of first event in the corresponding session.
- It is possible to have two sessions with same min time in which case you must break the tie by having `session` as second column. This ensures rows belonging to same session remain together.
- Finally for each session you sort by event time.

The window function could be replaced with a correlated sub query:

```
ORDER BY (
    SELECT MIN(time)
    FROM dlrcoco_events AS x
    WHERE x.session = dlrcoco_events.session
), -- other columns as described above
```

Comment: That's giving me a result of "FALSE" - but I'm looking at windowing functions and it looks like the answer is somewhere in there.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /home/627759.cloudwaysapps.com/gbtdtbrwrp/public_html/events_log.php on line 53

Comment: Ah, ok.  Windowing functions weren't introduced into MariaDB until 10.2.  I'm trying to write them on 10.1.  That explains a lot.

Comment: It is possible to replace window function with a sub query, but you seem to be unable to view the actual error message so experimenting will consume more time.

Comment: I just upgraded to MariaDB 10.2.  Fixed.  Now my events appear nicely ordered (https://dlrcoco.windowsonthepast.com/events_log.php)  and I can parse that list into an events dashboard to track events over time, by session (https://dlrcoco.windowsonthepast.com/sessions_view.php).  Thanks for your help.